# How can I link two database rows in different tables by dragging and dropping their corresponding React components onto each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, drag-and-drop

**Database**
The database contains two tables. Activities(teamId) is a foreign key that references Teams(id), so each activity can be assigned to one team and each team can take multiple activities.
Activities: id, description, teamId, status
Teams: id, leaderName, numMembers

**Webpage**
The webpage has two boxes, one with a list of activities showing the description, teamId, and status and the other box has a list of teams with the leaderName and the numMembers. Each box is a React component and each row in either list is a React component as well.

**Problem**
How can I program the list item components so that I can drag and drop the team onto an activity or an activity onto a team to link them together in the database? After dropping the list item, it links the two items in the database (by setting the teamId of the activity), snaps the list items back to their original spot, and update the teamId of the activity component visible on screen.

I know how to create the components and I have seen a lot of guides on how to reorder lists and such, but I want to link two items from two different lists.

Comment: `React-DnD` should allow you to achieve what you are after, but there will be a moderate amount of code required on your end. It provides Drag Sources and Drop Targets. A Drag Source designates a component as a draggable item with a configured type, such as 'activity' or 'team', and context (this could just be the id of the team / activity or the whole object). A Drop Target designates a component as a droppable area with a configured list of acceptable Drag Source types (i.e. 'activity' or 'item') and what logic to run when an accepted item is dropped into the target.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.